# Avoiding for loops to speed up the computation time with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am working with a 1800 x 900 matrix. For each cell in the matrix, I need to do a similar operation, which can be described with an example:

```
a1b1 a1b2 a1b3 .... a1b900
a2b1 a2b2 ..
.
a1800b1 ... ...   ..a1800b900
```

For each cell in a new matrix, I want its value to be equivalent to, the sum of its top left, top and top right neighbor. So, I want `a2b2 = a1b1 + a1b2 + a1b3`. For the top row, it could be the same value as the current cell.

I can easily do this using 2 for loops, but is there I way I can vectorize this so that it speeds up the whole process?

Comment: Numba is a great way to [speed up for loops](https://towardsdatascience.com/speeding-up-python-code-fast-filtering-and-slow-loops-8e11a09a9c2f) and works well in Numpy.

Comment: Use 2D convolution?

Answer (score 0):

you can vectorize it like below

```py
arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

arr2 = np.pad(arr, [(1,0), (1,1)], mode="constant")[:-1, :]

result = arr+arr2[:,0:-2]+arr2[:,1:-1]+arr2[:,2:]
```

**Description**

- `np.pad(arr, [(1,0), (1,1)], mode="constant")` pad zeros to left, right and top of matrix. index [:-1, :] will remove the last row effectively shifting the matrix by one row
- `arr2[:,0:-2], arr2[:,1:-1], arr2[:,2:]` will give top left, top and top right element for each corresponding element of `arr`. If there is no element it gives 0 (the zeros padded in previous step)

**Result**

```
## arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

## result
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  8, 12, 12],
       [17, 24, 28, 24],
       [29, 40, 44, 36]])
```